# Find the best constant C such that every simple planar graph on $n$ vertices has at most $C*n$ cliques.

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

last week I had such exercise on one of my courses: Prove there exists a constant $C$ such that every simple planar graph on $n$ vertices has  $\leqslant C·n$ cliques.

I proved by induction easily that $C=4$ is ok. But as Steve Jobs said, I stay hungry, stay foolish. Do you know what is the best known constant $C$ for that problem?

Comment: So I guess by a *clique* you mean any clique on $3$ or $4$ vertices? (A planar graph has no clique of $\geq 5$ vertices. If the cliques on $2$ vertices (i.e. the edges) are also counted, then the upper bound of $\leq 4n$ cliques does not appear to be true.)

Comment: @JossevanDobbendeBruyn yes, I mean exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a *clique* I shall mean any clique on $3$ or more vertices. I will prove that the constant $C = 4$ is optimal.

A *plane graph* is a drawing of a graph in the plane with no crossing edges. Let us say that a plane graph is a *plane triangulation* (or *maximally planar*) if every face (including the outer face) is bounded by a triangle. The following recursive construction gives for every $n \geq 3$ a plane graph with $n$ vertices and $4n - 11$ cliques:

1. Start with $G_3 := C_3$, the cycle in $3$ vertices, which has an essentially unique drawing in the plane. This is a plane triangulation with $3$ vertices and $1$ clique.
2. Suppose that $G_n$ is a plane triangulation with $n$ vertices and $4n - 11$ cliques. Choose a face $F$ of $G_n$ and let $a,b,c$ be the vertices bounding $F$. Add a vertex $d$ in the interior of the face $F$, and connect it to each of the vertices $a$, $b$ and $c$. This adds four new cliques to the graph, namely $\{a,b,d\}$, $\{a,c,d\}$, $\{b,c,d\}$ and $\{a,b,c,d\}$. Therefore the graph $G_{n+1}$ thus obtained has $n + 1$ vertices and $4(n+1) - 11$ cliques.

This shows that $C = 4$ is optimal.

Comment: Thank you very much!